# How should I deal with NaN being returned by freqz in R?

Tags: r, algorithm, matlab, frequency-analysis, digital-filter

I'm working on an optimization method to design digital filters and using `freqz`, from the `signal` package, to evaluate the candidates. However, I've been getting `NaN's` on the response given by `freqz`. This is a big problem to me because I need to calculate the mean squared error of this response.

The filter bellow is an example of this. The very first point on the response is a `NaN`.

**R Code:**

```
b <- c(-100.00000, 62.92546, -73.64395, -82.57045, 35.11388, -100.00000)
a <- c(100, 100, 100, -100, -100, -100)
r <- freqz(b,a)
r$h[1]
```

Running the equivalent code in Matlab I get `-Inf`, though. Which is just fine to my purpose.

**Matlab Code:**

```
b = [-100.00000, 62.92546, -73.64395, -82.57045, 35.11388, -100.00000]
a = [100, 100, 100, -100, -100, -100]
[h, ~] = freqz(b,a)
h(1)
```

My understanding is that, since `freqz` does its calculations based on the formula bellow, what must be happening is that we have a *value close to zero on the denominator* (note that the coefficients in `a` added together are *equal to zero*) but instead of `+/-Inf` (as Matlab does) it is mistakenly returning `NaN`.

[image]

The bottom line is that I think it should give the same response as Matlab.

---

### Work Around (with buts)

So far, this is what I've done as a work around:

```
r <- freqz(b,a)
if(anyNA(hw$h)){
  r$h[is.nan(r$h)] <- Inf
}
```

It does solve my problem but I wonder if there's a better way of doing so or if I should consider it a bug and report it, I'd be happy to help.
Maybe it has even been solved already (in case it is an actual bug).

---

### Additional Information

In case it is relevant here's my dev environment information:

```
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin13.4.0                
system         x86_64, darwin13.4.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.3                         
year           2015                        
month          12                          
day            10                          
svn rev        69752                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
```

Comment: I don't get it, `freqz(b,a)` as I've explained.

Comment: You have not mentioned the package where  `freqz` comes from. So one has to guess.

Comment: I see, sorry, it's the signal package. I've updated the description.